# Java cardlayouts/gui management

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, cardlayout

so i started learning java a year ago, and was given a couple of projects and systems here and there. What i commonly do in my java projects is open a jframe and then when the user chooses something or presses a button for instance that jframe closes and open a new one, even the "back" buttons closes the current jframe and opens the new jframe. Even my classmates do the same thing, but im different, im quite passionate with java codings, so i search for other ways. Then i find out about this cardlayout, is there any way to transfer the codes that i've written or i have to manually do everything? Start from scratch?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming in your various `JFrame`s you're creating content in a method (maybe the JFrame subclass constructor?). In this case what you'll need to do is copy that code into methods which you execute in sequence when creating the single `JFrame`, each function populating a different `JPanel` instance. You then need to add the `JPanel`s each one as a card. In the `actionPerformed()` of the buttons that currently move you to the next `JFrame` you will instead do a `cl.show(cards, index)`, when `cl` is the `CardLayout` instance and `index` is the index of the next card.

Comment: thank you! ill try to do that when i have the time and give you a feedback! Another thing though, ive seen cardlayout in action watching youtube videos but wont it just show me the same panel when i try to recall it? for instance if the user already tapped in a combobox of a certain panel, is there any way to reset it to the default values if i try calling that cardlayout?